# PHP 5.5 php.ini - how configure to show all error messages

Tags: php

I want to be made aware of all PHP errors - below is my php.ini config for this. Any advice on potential changes to ensure I'm make aware of any issues:

```
display_errors = On
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: On
;   Production Value: Off

display_startup_errors = On
;   Default Value: Off
;   Development Value: On
;   Production Value: Off

error_reporting = E_ALL
;   Default Value: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED
;   Development Value: E_ALL
;   Production Value: E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT

html_errors = On
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: On
;   Production value: On

log_errors = On
;   Default Value: Off
;   Development Value: On
;   Production Value: On

; max_input_time
;   Default Value: -1 (Unlimited)
;   Development Value: 60 (60 seconds)
;   Production Value: 60 (60 seconds)


; output_buffering
;   Default Value: Off
;   Development Value: 4096
;   Production Value: 4096

; register_argc_argv
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: Off
;   Production Value: Off

; request_order
;   Default Value: None
;   Development Value: "GP"
;   Production Value: "GP"

; session.bug_compat_42
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: On
;   Production Value: Off

; session.bug_compat_warn
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: On
;   Production Value: Off

; session.gc_divisor
;   Default Value: 100
;   Development Value: 1000
;   Production Value: 1000

; session.hash_bits_per_character
;   Default Value: 4
;   Development Value: 5
;   Production Value: 5

short_open_tag = Off
;   Default Value: On


;   Default Value: None
;   Development Value: "GP"
;   Production Value: "GP"

; session.bug_compat_42
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: On
;   Production Value: Off

; session.bug_compat_warn
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: On
;   Production Value: Off

; session.gc_divisor
;   Default Value: 100
;   Development Value: 1000
;   Production Value: 1000

; session.hash_bits_per_character
;   Default Value: 4
;   Development Value: 5
;   Production Value: 5

short_open_tag = Off
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: Off
;   Production Value: Off

; track_errors
;   Default Value: Off
;   Development Value: On
;   Production Value: Off

; url_rewriter.tags
;   Default Value: "a=href,area=href,frame=src,form=,fieldset="
;   Development Value: "a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry"
;   Production Value: "a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry"

; variables_order
;   Default Value: "EGPCS"
;   Development Value: "GPCS"
;   Production Value: "GPCS"
```

Also output_buffering - should this still be used if I'm on PHP5.5 with opcache enabled?

thx

Comment: You will of course want to remove the `;` as they are commenting out the functionality currently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your config looks fine for a development environment. For a production environment, you would want to turn display_errors off and possibly reduce the log level.

As to your question on output buffering, really your needs should dictate when use of output buffering is appropriate. Typically I would say it should only be used as a last resort, when no other approach will work for you.  Buffering your output causes you to use more memory to have to store all your output.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `Predefined Constants` page on php.net. It breaks down in detail many other error reporting options that you may not be aware of. One isn't limited strictly to the `php.ini` file itself for many of the error reporting options either, meaning you can specify options per site, per page, etc.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php